# Best Practices - SWT Table, TableViewer, EditingSupport

Tags: java, swt, tableviewer

I am adding a table to my main GUI. It does show up and has the data it is suppose to show. But I feel like I have a big mess of code and it is not structured correctly. I am looking for someone that uses SWT a lot to help me put the right pieces of code in the right places.

Class A - Main GUI with `TableViewer`

Class B - (`ArrayList`) Data for table / Class B1 - DataModel for `ArrayList` Structure

Class A - has method for creating `TableViewer`

```
  //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  //                         createTableViewer()                          //
  //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
private TableViewer createTableViewer(Composite parent) {
    viewer = new TableViewer(parent, SWT.MULTI | SWT.H_SCROLL | SWT.V_SCROLL | SWT.FULL_SELECTION | SWT.BORDER);
    createColumns(parent, viewer);
    table = viewer.getTable();
    table.setHeaderVisible(true);
    table.setLinesVisible(true);

    // Layout the viewer
    GridData gridData = new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true);
    viewer.setContentProvider(new ArrayContentProvider());
    *** Getting Array from Class B ***       
    viewer.setInput(AplotDataModel.getInstance().getArrayData());
    viewer.getControl().setLayoutData(gridData);
    return viewer;
}
```

Class A also has `createColumns()` method and a `createTableViewerColumn()` method.

```
 //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
 //                         createColumns()                              //
 //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
private void createColumns(final Composite parent, final TableViewer viewer) {
    String[] titles = { "ItemId", "RevId", "PRL", "Dataset Name", "EC Markup" };
    int[] bounds = { 150, 150, 100, 150, 100 };

    TableViewerColumn col = createTableViewerColumn(titles[0], bounds[0], 0);
    col.setLabelProvider(new ColumnLabelProvider() {
        @Override
        public String getText(Object element) {
            AplotDatasetData item = (AplotDatasetData) element;
            return item.getDataset().toString();
        }
    });

    col = createTableViewerColumn(titles[1], bounds[1], 1);
    col.setLabelProvider(new ColumnLabelProvider() {
        @Override
        public String getText(Object element) {
            AplotDatasetData item = (AplotDatasetData) element;
            return item.getRev().toString();
        }
    });

    col = createTableViewerColumn(titles[2], bounds[2], 2);
    col.setLabelProvider(new ColumnLabelProvider() {
        @Override
        public String getText(Object element) {
            AplotDatasetData item = (AplotDatasetData) element;
            return item.getPRLValue();
        }
    });

    col = createTableViewerColumn(titles[3], bounds[3], 3);
    col.setLabelProvider(new ColumnLabelProvider() {
        @Override
        public String getText(Object element) {
            AplotDatasetData item = (AplotDatasetData) element;
            return item.getDatasetName();
        }
    });

    col = createTableViewerColumn(titles[4], bounds[4], 4);
    col.setLabelProvider(new ColumnLabelProvider() {
        @Override
        public String getText(Object element) {
            AplotDatasetData item = (AplotDatasetData) element;
            return item.getECMarkupValue();
        }
    });
}

 //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
 //                       createTableViewerColumn()                      //
 //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
private TableViewerColumn createTableViewerColumn(String title, int bound, final int colNumber) {
    final TableViewerColumn viewerColumn = new TableViewerColumn(viewer, SWT.NONE);
    final TableColumn column = viewerColumn.getColumn();
    column.setText(title);
    column.setWidth(bound);
    column.setResizable(true);
    column.setMoveable(true);
    return viewerColumn;
}
```

**Question 1**: Is this the best practice to adding a table to my GUI class? Seems like a lot of code for the GUI class.

**Question 2**: Should the `createColumns()` method and the `createTableViewerColumn()` method be moved to Class B?

**Question 3**: My last column in the table is going to be a dropdown/combo box. So I am going to have to extend one class with `EditingSupport`. Should it be Class A or Class B?

Before I go any farther with this project I want to make sure I have it correctly structured.

Comment: +1, good question. I'm very anxious to see some good answers, since my code tends to look quite similar.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Answering this question is like answering which ice-cream flavor do you like :)

### Q & A

> **Question 1:** Is this the best practice to adding a table to my GUI
>   class? Seems like a lot of code for the GUI class.

If the code is less than its not a bad idea. But if -

1. The code is large (for me if its more than 100 lines).
2. Overall System is going to be more than some thousand of lines of code.
3. Someone else is going to maintain it
4. If I need plug-and-play nature, for example today `Table` is sufficient but in future I may use `Grid`.
5. If I am doing some custom drawing (doing some custom painting on windows paint event) or using custom controls, **THEN**

I normally prefer to sub-class the viewer/control. In this way I could maintain the separation between the bare-bone message pumping code, GUI controls and my data model.

> **Question 2:** Should the createColumns() method and the
>   createTableViewerColumn() method be moved to Class B?

No, You should not. As in your case the class B is your data model/supplier. The JFace programming model supports MVC architecture and if possible one should follow it. Suggested solution is to have a new class extending the TableViewer.

> **Question 3:** My last column in the table is going to be a
>   dropdown/combo box. So I am going to have to extend one class with
>   EditingSupport. Should it be Class A or Class B?

I would suggest you to go for a new class and use that in the extended TableViewer. One benefit is that in case you are writing data back to some db then your viewer class remain db/persistence layer agnostic.

### Code Sample

Below is a simple sample application. As you can see I can change my combo editor to text editor just by changing the `OptionEditingSupport` class. And also, the code looks clean and concise.

***Main Class***

```
package sample;

import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.FillLayout;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell;

public class SampleApp 
{
    public SampleApp(Shell shell)
    {
        AppPersonViewer personViewer = new AppPersonViewer(shell, SWT.BORDER|SWT.V_SCROLL|SWT.FULL_SELECTION);
        DataModel model = new DataModel(20);
        personViewer.setInput(model);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Display display = new Display ();
        Shell shell = new Shell(display);
        shell.setLayout(new FillLayout());
        new SampleApp(shell);
        shell.open ();

        while (!shell.isDisposed ()) {
            if (!display.readAndDispatch ()) display.sleep ();
        }

        display.dispose ();
    }
}
```

---

***Extended Table Viewer***

```
package sample;

import org.eclipse.jface.viewers.ColumnLabelProvider;
import org.eclipse.jface.viewers.TableViewer;
import org.eclipse.jface.viewers.TableViewerColumn;
import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridData;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Table;

public class AppPersonViewer extends TableViewer
{
    public AppPersonViewer(Composite parent, int style) 
    {
        super(parent, style);
        Table table = getTable();
        GridData gridData = new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true);
        table.setLayoutData(gridData);
        createColumns();
        table.setHeaderVisible(true);
        table.setLinesVisible(true);
        setContentProvider(new AppContentProvider());
    }

    private void createColumns()
    {
        String[] titles = { "First Name", "Second Name", "Age", "Country", "Likes SO" };
        int[] bounds = { 150, 150, 100, 150, 100 };

        TableViewerColumn column = createTableViewerColumn(titles[0], bounds[0], 0);
        column.setLabelProvider(new ColumnLabelProvider(){
            public String getText(Object element) {
                if(element instanceof Person)
                    return ((Person)element).getFirst();
                return super.getText(element);
            }
        });

        column = createTableViewerColumn(titles[1], bounds[1], 1);
        column.setLabelProvider(new ColumnLabelProvider(){
            public String getText(Object element) {
                if(element instanceof Person)
                    return ((Person)element).getSecond();
                return super.getText(element);
            }
        });

        column = createTableViewerColumn(titles[2], bounds[2], 2);
        column.setLabelProvider(new ColumnLabelProvider(){
            public String getText(Object element) {
                if(element instanceof Person)
                    return ""+((Person)element).getAge();
                return super.getText(element);
            }
        });

        column = createTableViewerColumn(titles[3], bounds[3], 3);
        column.setLabelProvider(new ColumnLabelProvider(){
            public String getText(Object element) {
                if(element instanceof Person)
                    return ((Person)element).getCountry();
                return super.getText(element);
            }
        });

        column = createTableViewerColumn(titles[4], bounds[4], 4);
        column.setLabelProvider(new ColumnLabelProvider(){
            public String getText(Object element) {
                if(element instanceof Person)
                    return ((Person)element).getLikes();
                return super.getText(element);
            }
        });

        column.setEditingSupport(new OptionEditingSupport(this));
    }

    private TableViewerColumn createTableViewerColumn(String header, int width, int idx) 
    {
        TableViewerColumn column = new TableViewerColumn(this, SWT.LEFT, idx);
        column.getColumn().setText(header);
        column.getColumn().setWidth(width);
        column.getColumn().setResizable(true);
        column.getColumn().setMoveable(true);

        return column;
    }
}
```

---

***Content Provider***

```
package sample;

import org.eclipse.jface.viewers.IStructuredContentProvider;
import org.eclipse.jface.viewers.Viewer;

public class AppContentProvider implements IStructuredContentProvider
{
    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see org.eclipse.jface.viewers.IStructuredContentProvider#getElements(java.lang.Object)
     */
    public Object[] getElements(Object inputElement) {
        if(inputElement instanceof DataModel)
            return ((DataModel)inputElement).getData().toArray();
        return null;
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see org.eclipse.jface.viewers.IContentProvider#dispose()
     */
    public void dispose() {
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see org.eclipse.jface.viewers.IContentProvider#inputChanged(org.eclipse.jface.viewers.Viewer, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object)
     */
    public void inputChanged(Viewer viewer, Object oldInput, Object newInput) {
    }
}
```

---

***Cell Editor Support***

```
package sample;

import org.eclipse.jface.viewers.CellEditor;
import org.eclipse.jface.viewers.ColumnViewer;
import org.eclipse.jface.viewers.ComboBoxCellEditor;
import org.eclipse.jface.viewers.EditingSupport;
import org.eclipse.jface.viewers.TableViewer;

public class OptionEditingSupport extends EditingSupport 
{
    private ComboBoxCellEditor cellEditor;

    public OptionEditingSupport(ColumnViewer viewer) {
        super(viewer);
        cellEditor = new ComboBoxCellEditor(((TableViewer)viewer).getTable(), new String[]{"Y", "N"});
    }
    protected CellEditor getCellEditor(Object element) {
        return cellEditor;
    }
    protected boolean canEdit(Object element) {
        return true;
    }
    protected Object getValue(Object element) {
        return 0;
    }
    protected void setValue(Object element, Object value) 
    {
        if((element instanceof Person) && (value instanceof Integer)) {
            Integer choice = (Integer)value;
            String option = (choice == 0? "Y":"N");
            ((Person)element).setLikes( option );
            getViewer().update(element, null);
        }
    }
}
```

---

***Data Model***

```
package sample;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class DataModel 
{
    private int samples;
    public DataModel(int samples) {
        this.samples = samples;
    }

    List<Person> getData()
    {
        List<Person> persons = new ArrayList<Person>();
        for(int i=0; i<samples; i++)
            persons.add(Person.createRandomPerson());
        return persons;
    }
}
```

---

***The Person Entity***

```
package sample;

import java.util.Random;

public class Person 
{
    private static final String[]   FIRST = {"Favonius", "Tim", "Brad", "Scott", "Linda"};
    private static final String[]   SECOND = {"Cruise", "Temp", "Abbey", "Adam", "Albert", "Thomas"};
    private static final String[]   COUNTRY = {"India", "USA", "Russia", "UK", "France", "Germany"};
    private static final int[]      AGE = {22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30};

    private static Random random = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());

    private String first;
    private String second;
    private String country;
    private String likes;

    private int age;

    public Person(String first, String second, String country, String likes, int age) 
    {
        super();
        this.first = first;
        this.second = second;
        this.country = country;
        this.likes = likes;
        this.age = age;
    }
    public String getFirst() {
        return first;
    }
    public String getSecond() {
        return second;
    }
    public String getCountry() {
        return country;
    }
    public String getLikes() {
        return likes;
    }
    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }
    public void setLikes(String likes) {
        this.likes = likes;
    }
    public static Person createRandomPerson(){
        return new  Person(FIRST[random.nextInt(FIRST.length)], 
                SECOND[random.nextInt(SECOND.length)], COUNTRY[random.nextInt(COUNTRY.length)], 
                "Y", AGE[random.nextInt(AGE.length)]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer with code applied.  I appreciate the time you put in on this answer.  I have redone my project and it seems to be working well.  The only thing I am seeing some issue with is the combobox does not show unless you click in the cell.  Is there way to make it show all the time?

Comment: @jkteater - the version shown in the above code demonstrates the in-place editing. For your need you should look at `TableEditor`. See this link http://git.eclipse.org/c/platform/eclipse.platform.swt.git/tree/examples/org.eclipse.swt.snippets/src/org/eclipse/swt/snippets/Snippet149.java. The concept is same for Combo.

Answer (score 0):

> simple way to insert the column name and Table item using TableViewer

**Student TableViewer**

```
package rcp_demo.Views;

import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite;
import org.eclipse.ui.part.ViewPart;
import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.wb.swt.SWTResourceManager;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Table;
import org.eclipse.jface.viewers.TableViewer;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TableColumn;
import org.eclipse.jface.viewers.TableViewerColumn;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Text;
import rcp_demo.TableView.Student;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TableItem;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class TaskView extends ViewPart {
    private Table table;
    private Text txt_search;
    private TableViewer tableViewer;
    public TaskView() {
        setTitleImage(SWTResourceManager.getImage("D:\\Icon\\Tasksview.png"));
    }

    @Override
    public void createPartControl(Composite parent) {
        parent.setLayout(null);
        //Search Text
        txt_search = new Text(parent, SWT.BORDER);
        txt_search.setBounds(21, 10, 238, 19);
        //TableViewer
        tableViewer = new TableViewer(parent, SWT.BORDER | SWT.FULL_SELECTION);
        table = tableViewer.getTable();
        table.setBounds(21, 47, 290, 213);
        table.setHeaderVisible(true);
        table.setLinesVisible(true);

                //Table(Student): TableViewerColumn Names

                String[] Col_names={"Stud_id","Stud_Name","Stud_Gender"};
                for(int i=0;i<Col_names.length;i++)
                {
                    TableViewerColumn tableViewerColumn = new TableViewerColumn(tableViewer, SWT.NONE);
                    TableColumn tblclmnNewColumn = tableViewerColumn.getColumn();
                    tblclmnNewColumn.setWidth(100);
                    tblclmnNewColumn.setText(Col_names[i]);

                }
                //Table(Student) Item List
                List<Student> std=new ArrayList<Student>();
                std.add(new Student("110","AAA","Male"));
                std.add(new Student("111","FFF","Female"));
                std.add(new Student("112","MMM","Male"));

                for(Student s:std)
                {
                    TableItem std_item=new TableItem(table, SWT.NONE);
                    std_item.setText(0,s.getStd_id());
                    std_item.setText(1,s.getStd_nm());
                    std_item.setText(2,s.getStd_gender());
//                  System.out.println(s);  
                }

    }
      public TableViewer getViewer() {
          return tableViewer;
  }
    @Override
    public void setFocus() {
        tableViewer.getControl().setFocus();

    }
}
```

---

Class : Student

```
package rcp_demo.TableView;

public class Student {

    private String std_id;
    private String std_nm;
    private String std_gender;

    public Student() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
    public Student(String sid,String snm,String sgender) {
        std_id=sid;
        std_nm=snm;
        std_gender=sgender;
    }

    public String getStd_id() {
        return std_id;
    }
    public void setStd_id(String std_id) {
        this.std_id = std_id;
    }
    public String getStd_nm() {
        return std_nm;
    }
    public void setStd_nm(String std_nm) {
        this.std_nm = std_nm;
    }
    public String getStd_gender() {
        return std_gender;
    }
    public void setStd_gender(String std_gender) {
        this.std_gender = std_gender;
    }

}
```

---

I got best practices for  SWT Table, TableViewer

thanks..